# Why need to get org.scalasbt sbt when I run activator run cmd?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

Downloaded and installed activator-1.2.12 without a problem in Windows OS. when I create a new paly framework project, and run the "activator run" cmd in the cmd line, it need get org.scalasbt sbt, and download a lot of jars like download all the world, very slowly;
Is there something wrong?  Need I just wait the download complete if I want to continue run the project? Thanks~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the minimal version of activator it is normal for it to take a lot of time to download all the dependencies. This will only happen the first time you start your project. From there it will use a cached version.

If you are using the full version then that's not normal. I remember Activator had a [bug](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/544) that made it download everything again even when the deps where available in the Activator package. Despite it being marked as fixed some people still complain this happens in Windows. If this is your case you may comment on that issue.

Unless you are on a very very slow connection the best solution is to just wait.

EDIT:

You can also try to copy the files from activator to your ivy cache. In Linux machines ivy cache is store in `~/.ivy2/cache`, in Windows I dont know but search for a folder with this name in your home folder. Then you just have to copy all the folders from `activator-1.2.12/repository` to `.ivy2/cache/`. It will still need to download some files...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! 
I am using the full activator version, as you said, I think it is not normal.The downloads had last nearly 2 days, and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: @sophie See my edit. Also you may want to try your luck in [Play framework Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework)

Comment: The Play 2.3.7 may have some bugs in windows OS. I tried an older version Play 2.2.6, and everything goes well.
Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

actually you don't really need the play/activator bloat to create and compile play apps.

- [Install sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Setup.html)
- Create a new folder for your app & a sub folder called project `$ mkdir -p newapp/project`
- Create a `sbt` build script in the `newapp/project` folder `$ vi newapp/project/plugins.sbt`
- Add the play framework repos (shown below) to your plugins.sbt file be sure to update the `x` in the `addSbtPlugin` version number to your desired version.  Example: `"2.2.3"`

> ```
> // The Typesafe repository  
>
> resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
>
> // Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
>
> addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.x")
> ```

- Create a new file called `build.sbt` in the root of your`newapp` folder `$ vi build.sbt`
- Add the following build information to your `build.sbt` file but remember to update some of the parameter values to match your app's values:

> import play.Project._
>
> name := "My first application"
>
> version := "1.0"
>
> playScalaSettings

Launch your new play app

```
$ cd newapp
$ sbt
```

After the project is loaded & dependencies are fetched you will have a fully functional play app with out having to download the bloated Activator packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed solution. I tried your idea step by step, but it did not work. when I launch the app, still the result is:   'F:\nxf-work\newapp>sbt
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.7 ...' and download a lot of things very slowly. Is it a normal state?

Comment: sophie - this behavior is normal.  SBT is downloading all of the required dependencies for the play framework.  At the end of it all should be left with a prompt in the the terminal that would look like this [My first application] $ and from here you can perform your play commands